# Bad RequiresPermission warning checking onRequestPermissionsResult

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

What´s the idea of `@PermissionChecker.PermissionResult` annotation?

I have a method that needs some permission:

```
@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION)
    private void startLocationUpdates() { ... }
```

But when I check the permission in `onRequestPermissionsResult` function it warns that I need

```
public abstract class PermissionUtil {

    /**
     * Check that all given permissions have been granted by verifying that each entry in the
     * given array is of the value {@link PackageManager#PERMISSION_GRANTED}.
     *
     * @see Activity#onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[])
     */
    @PermissionChecker.PermissionResult
    public static boolean verifyPermissions(int[] grantResults) {
        // At least one result must be checked.
        if (grantResults.length < 1) {
            return false;
        }

        // Verify that each required permission has been granted, otherwise return false.
        for (int i = 0, size = grantResults.length; i < size; i++) {
            if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

...

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == CODE_PERMISSIONS_LOCATION) {
            if (PermissionUtil.verifyPermissions(grantResults)) {
                startLocationUpdates();  /// WARNING!!
```

Check the `/// WARNING!!` line, there shouldn´t be a warning because it already granted...

Already tried with `@PermissionChecker.PermissionResult` annotation, what´s the point of it? how can I add `RequiresPermission` and check it here?

Comment: "I have a method that needs some permission" -- except that you have named a permission group in the annotation, not a permission.